# 'ImportError: No module named' even after installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, mrjob

At Jupyter Notebook, I try to import 'mrjob' Python 2.7 package after making sure that the package has been installed (pip2.7 list), but receive an error. Does anyone know what am I missing?

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-77ddb811471e> in <module>()
----> 1 from mrjob.job import MRJob

ImportError: No module named mrjob.job
```

Comment: What happens when you attempt to install the package again? Does it tell you it is already installed? `pip install mrjob`

Comment: Hi Nicarus, when I `pip2.7 install mrjob`, it says that "Requirement already satisfied".

Comment: Are you running this on Python 2.7 or do you have a different version also installed?

Comment: I have version 3.6 installed. Today I have just installed version 2.7 and am running this code on it.

Comment: Is Jupyter running in a virtualenv by chance?

Comment: I am not sure what Virtualenv is. Is there a way to check whether Jupyter is running in it? Initially I installed Python 3.5 by following this [link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) for OS X.

Comment: You installed 3.5 or 2.7? Also, did you mean 3.5 earlier when you said you had 3.6 installed? (3.6 is only in alpha right now).

Comment: What do you get when you type: `pip --version` and also `python --version` ?

Comment: What about `python --version`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and 3.6 was a typo... I had version 3.5 first installed, and today I have installed 2.7. I get 3.5 when I type `pip --version', I get pip 8.1.2, and Python 3.5.1.

Comment: By all accounts, I would think you are running Python 3.5 on Jupyter. One way to test would be to `pip install mrjob` and then run your code to see if you still get the error.

Comment: There is no error when I import 'mrjob' on Python 3.5. But my code (wish I could show it in this comment) works only on Python 2.7, therefore I installed Python 2.7 and pip2.7 install 'mrjob'.

Comment: OK. But this tells you that your Jupyter Notebook is running 3.5 and not 2.7. You need to reconfigure Jupyter to use 2.7. I don't have any experience with that, but I'm sure you could read their docs or search to find an answer.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Comment: Okay will do. :) Thank you very much for your time Nicarus.

Answer (score 0):

wo suggestions:

Make sure you don't have any file or directory permissions problems for the installed eggs and files in the site-packages directory.

If you have installed another instance of Python 2.6 (besides the Apple-supplied one in /usr/bin/python2.6), make sure you have installed a separate version of easy_install for it. As is, your output indicates it was almost certainly installed using the Apple-supplied easy_install in /usr/bin which is for the Apple-supplied Python. The easiest way to do that is to install the Distribute package using the new Python.