# Jupyter Python3 Kernel Install - Offline Only

Tags: python, linux, kernel, jupyter

Currently, I am working in a VM that does not have an internet connection.

I have Python2 installed installed on this machine and have been using it fine within Jupyter. I have installed Anaconda 3.6 and would like to create a kernel inside Jupyter for Python3 in addition to the Python2 Kernel that is present.

I have followed another stackexchange question: [How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter (IPython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)

and some documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3

The command that is doing something, just not the right something is:

```
/path/to/kernel/env/bin/python -m ipykernel install
```

No matter where I point it, it installs another kernel, but with Python 2.7...

Any suggestions?

Comment: make sure you are running `python3 -m ipykernel install`.

Comment: python3 is not recognized as a command, maybe that is where I am going wrong. How would I go about getting that recognized?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do `python3` if your Anaconda environment is Python 3.  If you do `/path/to/kernel/env/bin/python --version` what does it say?

Comment: That command gives me this: Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Comment: That is strange.  How do you know it is installing another Python 2.7 kernel?  Did you try giving the kernel an explicit name by doing something like `/path/to/env/bin/python -m ipykernel install --name py36 --display-name "Python 3.6"` (as described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments))?

Comment: I have printed the version with import platform, platform.python_version() - I have also tried giving it an explicit name and it reverts to python2

Comment: I am under the impression it is using the default python of 2.7 and not actually referencing the python 3.6 regardless of explicity telling it to. I think the only way around this may be to uninstall Python 2.7, but that may cause huge issues elsewhere...

Comment: Use `jupyter --paths` to determine where the kernels are being installed (`data`). And manually edit the `kernel.json` to point to right python.

Comment: Is the behavior any different if, instead of passing the env path on the command line, you actually do `activate my_python3_env` and then do `python -m ipykernel install --name ...` etc. from the activated environment?

Comment: @AChampion, I checked all paths brought up. There were 4 and there are 4 kernels active currently. One of the paths does not exist. One of the paths has python3 that I created and another kernel inside (could that be the problem?). The python3 kernel.json is referencing python 3.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I can't seem to activate as its saying it can not find the environment.

Comment: Okay, then it seems like something is messed up with your anaconda installation.  Try to get that resolved before dealing with this ipykernel issue.  If you do `conda info --envs` do you see your Python 3 environment listed?

Comment: The python 3 environment is not listed, only anaconda2.

Comment: A coworker and I got it to work correctly today. I was using the jupyter defaulted to 2.7 when I have to specify the 3.6 jupyter. Once that is done, it works correctly. Thanks AChampion and BrenBarn for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for my situation was to specify the python3 jupyter-notebook path instead of just using the default jupyter notebook.