# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on win7 using git-bash. I'm using anaconda with python 2.7.13. I want to run a jupyter server:

```
(myenv)
$ jupyter notebook
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
(myenv)
$ ipython notebook
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of jupyter and things started working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Answer (score 2):

I too faced same issue when invoking jupyter, but only difference is invoked jupyter from windows cmd prompt.

I uninstalled jupyter, updated pip and installed jupyter. Once installed and invoked, It worked perfectly.

Check If something like this can be done from your end as I see you are invoking from virtual env.

*** I have Python 3.5 64bit running in my system***

Comment: And there are good docs to [uninstall Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and to [install Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)