# Changing Python Executable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm pretty new to programming, and very new to doing so in a UNIX environment, so please bear with me.

When I run

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

in my Python 3 console, the output is

```
usr\bin\python3
```

and I'm able to import whatever libraries I've installed with pip3, no problem. 
 When I do so in my Jupyter Notebook running a Python 3 kernel, the output is

```
usr\bin\python
```

and the libraries that I've installed with pip3 are inaccessible to me.  What can I do to fix it so Jupyter is executing Python from the right place so I can use anything I've installed for Python 3 with pip3?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like Jupyter is actually using Python2, despite what the label says. Or python and python3 are the same program in your OS (unlikely)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter (IPython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short**

You need to [register your Python kernel with Jupyter](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html), for it to find the "right" Python

**Long**

Jupyter is meant to work with multiple kernels, and languages; it is common for some users to have tens of kernels, many can be the same language, with small differences. You usually need to "tell" jupyter about these kernels, it is often referred to as "Installing a kernelspec". In your case you need to:

- Install IPython & ipykernel for your Python 3
- Using the ipykernel you just installed: install the kernelspec.

You'll find instruction on above link, a few tip though:

- You can always safely replace `python` by `/full/path/to/python` if you are unsure.
- when using `pip`, you can always replace `pip` (or `pip3`)  by `/full/path/to/python -m pip` to use the pip linked to the python you want.
- If you are tempted to use `sudo`, don't. People telling you to use sudo get issues after a few month when their linux distribution need to be updated – unless you really know what you're doing.

Once you've registered the Python kernel with Jupyter, it should just appear in the menus. You may need to refresh your browser though.

Enjoy !