# Terminal and JupterLab use different installations of Python 3

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am pretty new to Python so please excuse me if this seems basic.

I am using JupyterLab and finding that although it uses Python 3, it is using a different installation to that used by my terminal. If I run `sys.executable` in terminal I get

> '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'

In JupyterLab I get

> '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/bin/python3.7'

In practice this means that if I `pip3 install package` in terminal, it won't be available in JupyterLab. I can do something like `%pip install package` or `/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/bin/python3.7 -m pip install package` in a cell in a notebook for e.g. but I feel this is probably not best practice to be using indefinitely and it would be better if these were in sync.

Running `jupyter kernelspec list` gives me

> Available kernels:
>
> python3    /usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources

Various answers and issues [like this](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) suggest editing the `kernel.json` but there isn't a file of this name in that folder.

I've also seen answers that involve creating virtual environments, which is something I'll probably be exploring but I'd like to deal with the issue at a more foundational level.

Can anybody explain what I am missing?

EDIT:

This is a duplicate of the question linked in the comments. Will look to close it but thought it might be useful making clear what steps I took because it takes a few clicks to get there.

In terminal:

```
pip3 install ipython
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Then if I run `jupyter kernelspec list` I get

> /Users/stodem01/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3

which contains a `kernel.json` with a path that matches that in terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270435/changing-python-executable

Comment: Thanks nima, I've gone through the answer there and it seems to work! Adding detail of what I did to the question but will vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Python Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270435/changing-python-executable)