# Library in pip list but not available

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I'm working in a python3 virtual env. I run jupyter (not installed in the venv). and in a jupyter notebook, I check the packages installed in the venv.

`!pip list`

Package         Version

cycler          0.10.0

kiwisolver      1.3.1
matplotlib      3.3.4
numpy           1.20.0

pandas          1.2.1
Pillow          8.1.0
pip             20.0.2

pkg-resources   0.0.0
pyparsing       2.4.7
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2020.5

scipy           1.6.0
seaborn         0.11.1

setuptools      44.0.0

six             1.15.0

but

`import pandas , numpy` fails with

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Why ?

Comment: Did you try installing pandas and numpy in the environment where jupyter is installed?

Comment: i think it will solve the problem, but i prefer to keep them separated. I'm running everything in a ubuntu 20.04 WSL in widows10 20H2 build 19042. I'm thinking that WSL have some problems,

Comment: You need to "register" your python env so jupyter can load it as a kernel. Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270435/changing-python-executable

Comment: Thanks it worked. Better explanation here https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/