# How to change pip in jupyter-lab

Tags: python

I need help for a jupyter lab config question. I have a conda environment, for example called `my-env`.

I followed these steps to added into jupyterlab:

```
conda activate my-env
conda install ipykernel 
ipython kernel install --user --name=my-env
```

And I start jupyterlab, and create the notebook with the environment `my-env`. it is all good. But if I use the magic command:

```
!which pip
```

to list what pip is used in the notebook created in the new environment, it still gives me the global pip rather than the env. I really want it to use the pip of `my-env` rather than the global one. How can I change this?

Comment: Isn't this already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729857/8508004)? Quote from end of that answer: "This should now successfully install packages using that virtual environment's pip!" For running in the notebook, you should be able to insure whatever pip is getting used, it will at least install to the right environment with `%pip install <package_name>`. Ideally though you should be using `%conda install` because you indicate Anaconda/conda as your main package manager. See [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

Comment: I know where the correct pip lies in. But the jupyter !pip command just does not use it. I am totally clear there are separate pips for different environments. My question is just: how can I change the pip which jupyter uses.

Comment: The answer I pointed you at said to use the full path when you call the `pip`. Not following why you say you know where it is but then bring up `!pip`? And for anyone else reading this quickly and not catching the possible nuances being discussed, **you shouldn't be using an exclamation point with `pip` or `conda` in any notebooks anymore, ideally. Use the magic variation, `%pip install`.**

Comment: More Jupyter-focused way of saying that is included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270547/8508004). Note: "when using `pip`, you can always replace `pip` (or `pip3`) by `/full/path/to/python -m pip` to use the pip linked to the python you want."  Add the exclamation point in front to run that inside a Jupyter notebook cell.

Comment: In fact I admit you are correct. Using %pip rather than the !pip resolves all the troublesome. However, I borrow a lot of notebooks from Google Colab. No one use %pip in fact. They all use !pip to install the package in the notebook. It is very hard to change all those commands or use the full path. I am just finding whether there are some easier way to fix this

Comment: "In fact I admit you are correct. Using %pip rather than the !pip resolves all the troublesome. However, I borrow a lot of notebooks from Google Colab. No one use %pip in fact" . Google Colab only added support for `%pip install` recently. So there was a reason no one used it. That is part of the problem with Google Colab: it isn't kept current with the features of modern Jupyter yet a lot of people don't realize that and don't do due diligence to keep up with currrent best practices. And I'm afraid I have to question your assertion ...

Comment: <continued>  "It is very hard to change all those commands". It literally just takes a single `sed` command to do a find and replace for `!pip install` to `%pip install`. I'll try to add the references where I found they add the magic, if I can dig it up tomorrow. You can see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about the modern magic install commands that were added to Jupyter in 2019.

Comment: And `%pip install` is as close to universal as can be now that Google Colab added support because it was essentially already the best way in Jupyter, including the up-and-coming JupyterLite. I should also add that by default usually automagics is on in most Jupyter installs and so these days in Jupyter you are better off without any symbol than with the exclamation point. Although explicit is better so everyone is clearer in what is happening.