# Remove old version of python and replace it

Tags: python, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed python 3.6 using `sudo apt-get python 3.6`. But python 3.5 is still installed. How do I remove 3.5 and set 3.6 as default in place of it so that when I type `python3 --version` in terminal it shows 3.6.5 instead of 3.5.2

Comment: Important applications are depending on python3.5 . About your typing `python3` : Better = `python36`, or whatever the alien python3.6 provides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ubuntu 16.04 distribution [comes with Python 3.5.1](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu). Many system apps depend on this default `python` package. Removing it will break those system apps. Overwriting it with a different python will screw up updates. So don't remove it!

Instead [make a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573587/190597) to run python3.6 as your user's default python and allowing it to co-exist with the system's python3.5.1.

Comment: I want to use python 3.6 in my jupyter notebook. It does not show up in the kernel selector. How do I add it? I am using pip

Comment: `jupyter` itself is a python program. It sounds like your `jupyter` is installed in the python3.5 distribution, but not for the python3.6 distribution. `pip` is also a python program. There is usually one pip for each distribution. To install a program for a certain distribution, you need to run the associated pip. The pip executable is usually in the same directory as the associated python executable. So (ideally, activate your python3.6 virtual environment and then) [`run /path/to/python3.6 -m pip install jupyter`](http://jupyter.org/install).

Comment: If you make a python3.6 virtual environment and activate it, then python3.6 will become your default `python`, so you can just run `python -m pip install jupyter`.

Comment: I have already installed jupyter I just want to add the py3.6 kernel

Comment: See [How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter (IPython)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28831854/190597).