# tensorflow is not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner in Anaconda. I am using jupyter notebook. Tensorflow is working on anaconda prompt but not opening in jupyter notebook. how to resolve this problem. Please help me out. I am a beginner.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG00s.png)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Answer (score 0):

You created an environment with tensorflow but you didn't install jupyter-notebook in it. You need to install the notebook in the same environment where you installed tensorflow:

On Windows from the anaconda command line you need to activate the environment where you installed tensoflow (in your case from the picture you posted it seems to be called tensorflow). Then install it there. Execute the following commands in the anaconda command line to achieve this and then start the notebook in tensorflow's environment

```
(base) C:\Users\usr>activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) C:\Users\usr>conda install jupyter
(tensorflow) C:\Users\usr>jupyter-notebook
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The python kernel in Jupyter notebook points to the root kernel. If you need a specific environment to be displayed in your Jupyter notebook, do the following

```
# Creating a custom environment in anaconda prompt with python 3.6
(base)C:\>conda create -n MyEnvironment python=3.6
(base)C:\>activate MyEnvironment 
# Install your custom pacakges like tensorflow etc
(MyEnvironment)C:\>pip install tensorflow
(MyEnvironment)C:\>python -m ipykernel install --name MyEnvironment
(MyEnvironment)C:\>jupyter notebook
```

Now you should be able to see both root kernal and MyEnvironment kernel version in Jupyter notebook