# Python path and Juptyter notebook on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've installed Python and Jupyter in a folder. And then, I moved this folder. Python was in **E:\Python** and Jupyter in **E:\Python\Scripts**. Now, Python is in **E:\Projects\Tests\Python** and Jupyter is in **E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts**.

When I try to start Jupyter notebook with command Line (`jupyter notebook`) from **E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts**, I have the error :

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'"E:\Python\python.exe" "E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook'
```

Jupyter kept the old Python path.

How can I specify the new path? Is there a command line like

```
start "E:\Projects\Tests\Python\python.exe" "E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook'
```

(this doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that jupyter doesn't find the new directory in the `%path%` variable.

Do you find your new directories in the `%path%` variable when you type

```
echo %path%
```

in a command window? If no, try to add it by typing in the command line

```
setx path "%path%;E:\Projects\Tests\Python\python.exe;E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe"
```

---

EDIT: Changing the windows `%path%` is not desired.

Preferred is a change of the `ipython_config.py` file

In that case, open a command window and type

```
ipython profile create
```

and

```
ipython locate
```

This will output you the path of your `.ipython` folder, which contains now a default `ipython_config.py`. Go to this line

```
## lines of code to run at IPython startup.
#c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
```

and replace the second line by

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['import sys; 
                                     sys.path.append("E:\Projects\Tests\Python\"); 
                                     sys.path.append("E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts\")']
```

This will append your new paths TEMPORARY to the `path` variable every time jupyter notebook starts iPython. So every time you move your folders you would have to adjust these lines in the ipython_config.py.

Comment: Actually, no because I don't want to change the path variable on my system. I would like to be able to move my folder without having to modify windows path.
Is there a line in the Jupyter config file where it's possible to specify Python path ? It would be a nice solution.

Comment: @Peter. I see. I edited my answer. Does this work for you and fit your boundary conditions better?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall jupyter.

pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall jupyter

Comment: I would like to avoid that. Because I would like to be able to move my folder when I want.
That's why I try to find a way to change this python path in Jupyter or to use a command line like `start "E:\Projects\Tests\Python\python.exe" "E:\Projects\Tests\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook'`. This last solution doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: ok have look there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072803/4776701

But is this really a better solution?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it doesn't help for what I'm looking for.