# Why python's versions differ when called from Terminal and from Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, version, atom-editor

When I run Python from the terminal and from `Atom`, different versions of python are called. As a consequence, there are packages that I can call without problems from the terminal but that I cannot call from `Atom`. Here are the details:

When calling `python` from the `terminal`, I get version 3.7.1

```
$ python
Python 3.7.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 13 2018, 09:50:42) 
[Clang 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on darwin
```

(I get exactly the same if I type `python3`instead)

Now when looking at the `python` version from `Atom` i get version 3.6.5 with

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version
3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 13:44:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
```

how come? how can I make `Atom` get the same version as the version the Terminal is getting?

**Failed attempts**

Looking at the `PATH` with the command `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)` here is what I get:

From Atom:

```
['', '/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', 
'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cycler-0.10.0-py3.6.egg', 
'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/mymac/.ipython']
```

From the Terminal:

```
['', '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', 
'/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', 
'/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
'/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa']
```

It seems `Atom` is using the version of Python of `pyenv` given the following command and output:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/mymac/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.5
```

according to the [github page of pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I entered `pyenv virtualenv 3.7.1`. Then when entering `$ pyenv versions` at least the version 3.7.1 was in the list:

```
* system (set by /Users/mymac/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.5
  3.7.1
```

But that didn't solve the problem with `Atom`

I then visited the [conda page](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) aboute managing environment and ran the following commands:

```
$ conda create --name myenv
```

It ran without problem, but the problem persists

I then tried to run more specifically `$ conda create -n myenv python=3.7.1` but got: `CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /Users/mymac/anaconda3/envs/myenv`

As pointed by @jmh Then I tried: `$ source activate 3.7.1` and got the following prompt: `(3.7.1) user:~ user$`

I could successfully choose the correct the correct virtualenv. But then upon opening `Atom` the problem persisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had actually to change the `Path` in the `.json` file of the jupyter kernel. First I checked the list of jupyter kernel:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
julia-0.6    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-0.6
julia-1.0    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
python3      /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I then `cd` the above python path and, I found the file `kernel.json` inside and opened it:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/path/to/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

In that file, I then changed the line `/path/to/python` by the python path I got when typing the following in Terminal:

```
$ which python
/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Relaunched `Atom` and it finally worked!

The hints of the [github page of jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) helped also a lot!

Comment: Alright!  Good catch!  I was so focused on virtual environments that is all I thought about!  Glad you got it fixed, Sorry if I lead you down a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

You must have multiple (different versioned) Python interpreters on your computer. Open the Command Palette in Atom and choose "Python: Select Interpreter". Select the Python version you wish to use.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @RealPawPaw. I tried to look for what you pointed to but couldn't find it. I added the screenshots of what I'm seeing in `Atom`. It's probably very silly but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple versions of python you should be using virtual environments. The version of python used from the terminal will depend on which virtual environment you have activated. Atom will use the same then.
Activate which version of python you want and then run Atom.

If you are using Anaconda then install conda environments. Its very simple if you using Anaconda. A few additional steps are required if you are not using it.

The internet is littered with directions to create virtual environments.

I created an environment named py27 for python 2.7. When I activate this environment it shows up on the cursor line like so:

[image].

If you don't see this your environment has not been activated. To activate on a Mac type `source activate py27`. I don't think you need the word source on a pc but I can't test that.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @jmh, I tried to look at the documentation for virtual environments, and wrote the corresponding websites that I visited as welle as the different commands that I tried, but I still couldn't resolve the problem. do you have any other hints?

Comment: i did add a few more comments to my answer?  If that doesn't help, let me know.  After you activate a virtual environment does it leave you any messages?  Do all  this from same terminal window. I have time to help you if this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a Mac or PC?

Comment: many thanks for your time @jmh. I also updated my question accordingly. I could successfully choose the correct the correct virtualenv. But then upon opening `Atom` the problem persisted

Comment: i'll have to think on this.  I just tried again and it works fine for me..  i'll get back to you when/if I can come up with something...

Comment: It maybe not have to do with the virtualenv but rather with the installed jupyter kernel installed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython