# Anaconda and jupyter notebooks: How to switch the used virtual environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I have got two anaconda environments. The base one and my testing environment called `testenv`. This environment works without an issue for example with the PyCharm IDE.

[image]

When starting a jupyter server straight from the pictured directory by issuing `jupyter notebook` my scripts/notebooks complains about missing packages.

This tells me it is using `base` environment instead of my `testenv` environment. But as the screenshot show, its not the one thats activated.

So the question is: **How can I set the virtual environment used by jupyter?**

Used versions:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4
- Python 3.7.1
- Conda 4.5.12

---

**[Edit]** It turned out that jupyter was not even installed in my environment. I was assuming to be able to use the installation coming from `base`. After installing jupyter within my environment everything was working as *expected*.

Comment: To begin using a virtual environment, it needs to be activated first. Hot "switching" never happens. Say if you have a program written in `env-1` and you switch to `env-2` then reopening that program in `env-2` might complain about certain dependencies that were only available in `env-1`

Answer (score 1):

This is usually foolproof for me. However, it does not allow switching virutal env on the fly. [Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment).

## Windows

```
$ activate testenv
$ jupyter notebook
```

## Linux

```
$ source activate testenv
$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Stupid me... jupyter was not even installed in my `testenv`... got confused!

Comment: Great! Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to be able to switch between your envs even on the fly from within Jupyter, this should also do the trick.

[How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter (IPython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)