# Cannot import pandas when using Spyder under virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas, conda, spyder

In my "base" environment, installing pandas and then importing it using the Spyder IDE works just fine.

However, this is no longer the case when working under a virtual environment.
In my terminal, I created a Python 2.7 environment named `bodhi`:

`conda create -n bodhi python=2.7`

I activated it:`conda activate bodhi`

I then installed spyder: `sudo -i apt-get install spyder`

And finally I installed pandas: `conda install pandas`

Typing `conda list` confirms that pandas 0.24.2 was installed properly.

After opening Sypder, typing `import pandas` in the IPython console returns the following ImportError: `No module named pandas`.

What am I doing wrong? 
I am fairly new to virtual environments so I apologize if the question seems obvious!

Comment: I think you need to install Spyder in your environment with conda instead of apt-get because the latter install it globally.

Comment: That was it! Removing Spyder and then reinstalling it using conda did the trick. Thanks a lot, Carlos!

Answer (score 0):

Your conda env isn't the same as your kernel. Open an `IPython` console `Ctrl-T` and do your installs and environment management there as described [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connecting-to-a-console).

You can also work with your kernel from the console using some of the commands described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840041/10553976

Importantly: `path/to/python -m ipykernel install <options>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Charles. Just for the record, importing pandas under the console in the virtual environment works alright.

Comment: Yea I deleted it because it's not the best approach IMO but I'll restore it