# Unable to load matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm Unable to load matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook but woking fine in python command line shell,

Is there anything I need to configure to make it working?

Following is the error I'm getting in Jupyter Notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-99ba79ecbbfb> in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

And in command line I can access it like the following:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:47:09) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>>
```

Comment: have you installed jupyter notebook using pip3?

Comment: @Ruturaj - I followed `https://jupyter.org/install` `pip3 install jupyterlab` and `pip3 install jupyter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it's working now I ran the following command as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check if you installed `matplotlib` using pip3 (if you used pip3 to install `jupyter notebook`, which looks like is your case).

Another way is to add the path of site-wide packages (where of course matplotlib is installed). In your Jupyter notebook console:

```
import sys
PATH = '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/'
sys.path.append(PATH)
```

Comment: I have installed jupyter notebook using pip3 but it's showing the following in the about page `The version of the notebook server is: 5.7.8
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar  4 2019, 09:01:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]`, How I can make it working as python3. I created the new book as python3 but still it's executing as python2.7

Comment: can you see? `jupyter kernelspec list`

Comment: `Available kernels:
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

Comment: install with: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` && `python3 -m pip install jupyter` - including ipython - `pip3 install --upgrade pip jupyter ipython`

Comment: still it's same

Answer (score 0):

Notebook is launched from another virtual python environment.

You can check paths to python interpreters, that run your notebook and interactive shell:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I'm sure, they will be different.

Comment: Yes it's different `/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7` but I created this book as python3 also I tried to change it to python3 from the `kernel` menu. How i can make it working as python3