# Change environment for Jupyter Notebook (Python3)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I install package using pip on my computer, they are not available in my Jupyter Notebooks. From what I figured out, they are not in the same environment. When I run

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

on the Notebook, I get

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
```

while on the terminal I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

What do I do to fix this? All answers I found online assume conda in installed, but I do not use conda. Ideally I would just change the default environment the Jupyter Notebook runs in but I can't figure out how...

**EDIT**

I tried adding the environment as suggested in another article by using the following code in terminal:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 --name 'Py3’
```

But it returns

```
quote>
```

Which I don't really understand.

Comment: Related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by uninstalling Python 3 and then using homebrew and pyenv to install a new version in a more controlled manner and make it the system default. After a reboot it then worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should change jupyter kernel via Kernel tab:

[image]

Use the explanation here if you want to add more kernels to jupyter:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: Unfortunately I only have 1 option there which is Python 3 (but in the wrong env). Added feedback on how to add an env in the description cause it doesn't work.