# Switch to python 3 interpreter in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook (**without Anaconda**) and cannot import packages anymore. I certainly have these packages as it work in Pycharm. I always use Python 3.x but it seems to be trying to use (see picture):

[image]

I also cannot switch interpreters within Jupyter as I only have the option of Python 3 (see picture).

[image]

I am asking the question as I have read that uninstalling python 2.x could break my system, so I'm hoping there is a simple solution much like you would change interpreters in Pycharm.

Is there a command I can type that will switch interpreters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this supposing you have a windows OS-

1. upgrade to Jupyter with `pip install -U jupyter`
2. install Python3
3. install Jupyter again using `pip3 install jupyter`
4. install Python3 kernel using `ipython3 kernelspec install-self`

Then, it must work fine.

Else Checkout some valuable Links-
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)
[Github Issues](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270)

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention I use Mac. I have used homebrew to install jupyter and have uninstalled/reinstalled many times. I also have python 3 already