# Unable to add another kernel to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I already referred to this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)

Currently am using `Jupyter Notebook` which has `Python2` kernel only. But my server has both Python2 and Python3.

However, I would like to add `python3` kernel. By following the above post, I tried the below

```
1 !mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments && virtualenv env && virtualenv -p python3 env && . env/bin/activate   #activated virtual environment
2 !jupyter kernelspec list  #lists only Python2 kernel  
3 !which python3 # outputs the python3 path `/usr/bin/python3`
4 !pip install ipykernel  # stream of requirement already satisfied messages
5 !python3 -m pip install ipykernel  # error-1
6 !python3 -m ipykernel install --user # error-2
```

I get the below errors

error-1

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit' -> '/tmp/pip-rgd7fgjj-uninstall/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit
.....
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'toolbars.py'
```

error-2

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado-6.0.4.dist-info'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/usr/bin/python3: No module named ipykernel
```

**Questions**

1. When I activate the `virtualenv`, all the commands that I execute after activation (line 2,3,4,5,6) are being run in my virtual env. Am I right?
2. line 4 has a stream of requirement already satisified messages. Am trying to install `ipykernel` in my virtual environment. Why does it say it's already satisfied. Is it looking at my system installation because the message has python2.7.2?
3. Line 5, Why do I get `permission denied` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're running everything from jupyter notebook using `!` which starts a temporary shell for every command, thus all your commands are executed in a different shell. Hence, virtualenv is **not** activated, and you're getting requirements satisfied when you use `pip` as it's checking system's python.

You need to use the terminal to activate virtual environement (though it can be done using jupyter, but a bit cumbersome):

From the terminal, first activate your virtualenv (which whould have python 3 as you mentioned it when you created this env (`virtualenv -p python3 env`)):

```
. python-virtual-environments/env/bin/activate
```

It should show something like this `(env) $` when activated, then if you check python and pip, it should give your env's python and pip.

```
(env) $  which python
home/abcd/python-virtual-environments/env/bin/python
(env) $  which pip
/home/abcd/python-virtual-environments/env/bin/pip
```

Now, you can install kernel if it's not already installed:

```
(env) ➜ pip install ipykernel
```

Comment: But may I check `virtualenv -p python3 env` where should we use this?

Comment: You don't need to use this anymore, you used it earlier when you installed virtualenv.

Comment: Nice, It means your env is activated now. You can install packages in it and launch jupyter from there.

Comment: Or it is showing the path of jupyter notebook? All my installations and packages only will only go to `virtual env` provided in code above. Am I right?

Comment: yeah, pwd is showing the path of where your notebook is stored, Yes, all your installations will now go in env. in fact, you can check `which jupyter` will show jupyter path inside of env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216441/discussion-between-the-great-and-kharshit).

Comment: can help with this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590428/setting-the-path-for-pyenv