# Setting the path for Pyenv

Tags: python-3.x, bash, unix, environment-variables, pyenv

I am trying to set the load path for Pyenv in my server `.bashrc` file.

I am following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) where it asks us to set `pyenv` to the load path

However, in my `.bashrc`file, I already see the below commands

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

And how is it different from the below provided in the tutorial shared above?

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

May I know what does `if...fi` block does in the code shown above?

Comment: The `if` block just makes it so the `~/.bashrc` will continue to function without error, even if you uninstall pyenv

Comment: Hi, can I know what does this exactly mean? `command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"`?  what does `dev/null` or `2>&1` mean? can help me translate this into words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly bash's syntax.

**#1.**

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

is equivalent to

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
```

as in the first case, you're declaring a variable named `PYENV_ROOT` then using it.

**#2.**

`if` and `fi` are how you write if-statements in bash.

**#3.**

[`command -v pyenv`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=command+-v) is used to execute a command (`pyenv`) in this case, the `-v` option prints the pathname e.g.

```
$ command -v python
/usr/bin/python
```

```
if command -v pyenv 1
```

means that if the command `pyenv` is found, then execute `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

**#4.**

Here, `>/dev/null 2>&1;` is used to discard the output. read more about it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10508843/6210807).

Hence, two blocks of code are almost same, the only differences are: the first one has a `if-block` and second one has one extra command `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"`.

Comment: I was searching for this Q and A. It helped me very much. Also I was not sure how to put 3rd 4th 5th lines of blockquote 1 into terminal/konsole. Searching the net I got that from terminal you have to use 'echo' with '-e' option with '-e' option's qualifier '\n' OR you have to nano the .bashrc. Am I right? Thank you very much.