# Python 3 Kernel not showing in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter

I am facing a problem in a GCP(Google Cloud Platform) instance. The Jupyter notebook is not showing anymore the kernel(Python 3).

[image]

Anyone know the solution? I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython) but didn't work

Comment: I assume that your issue is in a self installed Jupyter on a GCP VM and not in a Notebook instance in AI platform, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have several notebooks on AI Platform:

- R 3.6
- Python 2 and 3
- Tensorflow Enterprise 1.15
- Tensorflow Enterprise 2.3
- PyTorch 1.4

At the time of writing this post, all of them give the option to choose Python 3 as kernel type ([see available options here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8jlZ.png)). I suggest that, if you are using an old instance, you migrate your code to any of these instance types in [AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs)