# Jupyter using WSL2: Kernel 'Python 3' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I wasn't able to open find the python3 kernel when I launched the jupyter notebook using WSL2.

I tried the recommendations from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython).

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall python3

python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user

jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

I tried to check the kernelspec list:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Error:

```
> [ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Kernel 'Python 3' is referencing a kernel
> provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the
> appropriate package has been installed and retry. No kernels available
```