# Cant import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

skitlear is installed, however whe I run `import sklearn` i get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`
please see bellow:

```
System:
    python: 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: C:\Users\33826\Anaconda3\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0

Python dependencies:
          pip: 21.2.2
   setuptools: 58.0.4
      sklearn: 1.0.2
        numpy: 1.21.5
        scipy: 1.4.1
       Cython: None
       pandas: 1.4.1
   matplotlib: 3.5.0
       joblib: 1.1.0
threadpoolctl: 2.2.0

Built with OpenMP: True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21264/3775665260.py in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()')
----> 2 import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

***EDITED as per Laci request***

1.Output for `jupyter kernelspec list`:

```
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

2.Kernel.json content:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\33826\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf_plates\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

3.Output of `where python`:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: It seems that in the fist line `sklearn` works fine, but not in the second line. Do you have more kernels installed? If so, try to change it in jupyter notebook.

Comment: what do you mean by "more kernels installed"? how would I check that? and how to change it if so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython,   https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove, https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-change-the-kernel-version-in-Jupyter-Python-Notebooks

Comment: If you cannot fix the problem, edit your post and show us the following: 1) result of `jupyter kernelspec list` command - it shows folder location of your kernels 2) In that(those) folder(s), open up file(s) kernel.json and show them to us. 3) result of `where python` command at command prompt.

Comment: @Laci Edited as per your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `jupyter` uses an environment called `tf_plates`, but `scikit-learn` is installed in the `base` environment. You can

1. Install scikit-learn in this environment:

```
conda install --name tf_plates scikit-learn
```

2. Other alternative is to use the `base` environment in jupyter:

In your `kernel.json` file change `C:\\Users\\33826\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf_plates\\python.exe` to `C:\\Users\\33826\\Anaconda3\\python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Go to anaconda cmd or miniconda cmd and put this

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

after that restart spyder or  pycharm

Comment: still the same outcome, I am using Jupyter notebook