# Terminal Python version is different from Jupyter Notebook(not installed through Conda) default version

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, terminal

Discovered that my Jupyter notebook is using Python 3.10.1, while my terminal is using version 3.7.0. This discrepancy caused my installed packages to fail while trying to import.
How can I fix this problem?

[Screenshot of discrepancy between terminal and jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWVPB.png)

Commands ran:

```
import sys
sys.version
Output: '3.10.1 (v3.10.1:2cd268a3a9, Dec  6 2021, 14:28:59) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]'

!python3 --version
Output: Python 3.7.0
```

I installed a package using the terminal, and tried to import for usage in the Jupyter Notebook Kernel. While importing, I kept getting an error preventing my from using the package. Upon further inspection, I realized I had 2 versions of Python... How can I fix this issue and ensure that Jupyter Notebook will be using the same version of Python in the terminal in the future?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072803/1467914

Comment: If you for sure only ever want to use the same kernel all the time, then add the correct one, and remove the incorrect one. Otherwise, you can choose or change kernels from the Kernel menu in notebook.

Comment: Note that if you are using or might use conda environments (miniconda or anaconda), then these instructions are easy to follow: [how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084](https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084)