# How to upgrade python 2.7 of Jupiter Notebook (SageMath 8.8)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, upgrade, sage

I am using SageMath Notebook 8.8 where I have python 2.7.
How can I update the python version of Notebook to 3.12?

As I am running a code where I receive a lot of syntax errors and when I search for the solution I see that it is because of the version of the python (for example "def print(self):" gives me syntax error on my current version)

I want to see python3 here:

[image]

I have tried the lines below ([using in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)):

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user

python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

but I receive this error on the line python3 -m pip install ipykernel:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipykernel
```

(I am using Windows 10 home edition, and I have python 3.9.13 on it. Can I add it to my Jupiter Notebook?)

Comment: it isn't clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to convert *the python code* to be compatible with python 3?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: No. I wan't to update my python inside jupyter notebook to 3.12.

Comment: Are you trying to add a 3.12 python kernel? https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: SageMath 8.8 is almost 5 years old. Would you consider upgrading to a newer version of SageMath?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: with the help of your comment I tried ipykernel, but again with error. I editted my question and added its information

Comment: @John Palmieri: Is there any way to straightly upgrade it without first removing SageMath8.8 and then trying to install SageMath 10.2?

Comment: You can in theory have multiple versions of SageMath installed on your machine: you should not have to remove the old version. I have no experience with Windows, but see the directions at https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/index.html#windows.

Comment: @John Palmieri: Thanks, I installed another Sagemath in different drive and it worked.