# Switch anaconda python version which runs in IDE

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to coding. I installed anaconda2 and installed python36 as a environment in anaconda2. And I activate python36 in the anaconda prompt. Then, I run the following codes on pycharm to test whether my version is switched to python36.

`print('3 / 2 =', 3 / 2)`

It returns

```
3 / 2 = 1
```

The result supposed to be 1.5. Seems it doesn't work.

Is there any thing wrong with my steps? Can I switch version which runs in IDE by activate py36 in prompt?

Another question is what is the difference between anaconda3 and anaconda2 which activated python3.x? Do I need download anaconda3 and switch interpreter in my IDE sitting?

Comment: You need to change the project interpreter in PyCharm to anaconda's interpreter. And, btw you can always run your scripts in anaconda's ide named Spyder.

Comment: @Kishor Thank you. What the activate command for? Only activate py36 in prompt?

Comment: google it! I think you can go to Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter and change the interpreter. I am not sure though. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating an environment at the command line has no impact on the environment loaded by PyCharm. This is covered in [Is it ok having both anacondas 2.7 and 3.5 installed in the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442494/is-it-ok-having-both-anacondas-2-7-and-3-5-installed-in-the-same-time/37442942#37442942). The gist is, you can choose the environment in PyCharm in the Project Interpreters section of the Settings/Preferences dialog box. See [Conda Support Creating Conda Environments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html) for more details.