# Python error in mean installation

Tags: python, node.js, cmd, mean-stack

I am php developer and now i want to build project with mean.io. and getting some errors in command line, can anyone help me to get out of these or let me know why these errors are showing up.
I installed node.js,git and python.

I wrote the following commands.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
 $ cd mean
 $ npm install && npm start
```

Following errors are showing in cmd.

```
Binary has a problem: Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\D:\mean\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-57\binding.node
erb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\mean\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\mean\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\mean\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mean\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mean\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mean\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
```

Comment: Would you please share which version of python you have installed? To get it, use `python -V`

Comment: python version is 3.6 and my OS is windows 10 64 bit

Comment: You can install Python2.7 along with v3. See the solutions here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341184/can-i-install-python-3-x-and-2-x-on-the-same-computer`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and this problem was due to older 32-bit version of node.js.
I am posting the answer to help others.
My OS is window 10-64 bit and i removed node.js 32 bit and installed updated 64 bit version of node.js ,Then run the commands

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
 $ cd mean
 $ npm install && npm start
```

And i found no errors.Now mean is running correctly.